# Testing a method with return type void

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I'm new to software testing. In a tutorial I read that I can test some methods like this:

```
@Test
 public void testMultiply() {
   MyClass tester = new MyClass();
   assertEquals("10 x 5 must be 50", 50, tester.multiply(10, 5));
 }
```

So I have to pass some parameters to a method and get a return value.
But in my case I have some classes without any parameters and return values:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

public void Main(){
  methodA();
  methodB();
}

public void methodA(){
  // connect to URL
  // get some data
  for(int i=0; i<someThing; i++){
    al.add(data);
  }
}
public void methodB(){
  // do something with al
}
```

Is it also possible to test them? For example whether the right value comes from the URL in `methodA()`.

Comment: Sure you can.  It looks like `methodA()` is modifying the internal state of an `ArrayList`, so you can make your test class check the contents of the list before and after executing the method.

Comment: Yes it is depending on what is important in that you can use mockito to verify if a implementation was called or you can verify the object that it mutates.

Comment: Of course. Usually, if no error occurs during the call to the function without no parameters and return value, it means that the function could work. Of course, it's not true at all. For this purpose, you could simply use the debugger and test the flow of the program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test void method with Junit testing tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244541/how-to-test-void-method-with-junit-testing-tools)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to test methods that don't return anything (`void`), but you must test that method's side effects.  It should have some side effects, otherwise such a method is useless.

The side effect here is that `al` is changed.  As written, this class doesn't have any other methods that expose `al`.  Add a getter method that returns either the `ArrayList` or a specific element of the `ArrayList`.  Then your test method can call the getter method to retrieve the value(s) and compare it(them) with the expected value(s).

Comment: Should I add this method only so that the test class can call it? Even if I don't actually need it in my code?

Comment: How is this data being used?  If it's being used by other methods such as `methodB`, then you can use `methodB` and test its side effects.

Comment: @user1170330 Yes. You're writing a testable component, and that means writing enough accessors that you can test it. If these shouldn't be called in production, document them as such.

Answer (score 2):

Methods without parameters are used for their return value or for their side effects. Therefore, testing of these methods consists of these three steps:

- Set the object being tested to the initial state before calling the parameterless method
- Call the parameterless method
- Check the return value or the side effects of the parameterless method

The last step can check either the new state of the object being tested, or the results of its work in the overall environment of the system.

Here is a small example:

```
class Calculator {
    private int left, right, result;
    public void setLeft(int val) { left = val; }
    public void setRight(int val) { right = val; }
    public int getResult() { return result; }
    public void add() { result = left + right; }
    public void multiply() { result = left * right; }
}
```

You could test its `multiply()` method like this:

```
@Test
public void testMultiply() {
    // Set the object being tested to the initial state 
    Calculator tester = new Calculator();
    tester.setLeft(5);
    tester.setRight(10);
    // Call the method
    tester.multiply();
    // Check the new state
    assertEquals("10 x 5 must be 50", 50, tester.getResult());
}
```

This sample tests side effects of the method. Testing a method with a return value and no side effects would combine the call of the method with its check on the assertion line.

Comment: Would be worth clarifying: methods without parameters *or a return value* are used for their side effects. Methods without parameters, but with a return value, needn't have side effects (e.g., getter methods).

Comment: @chiastic-security That is a fair observation, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly you can test a method with no parameters.

It may be that an example is the best way of seeing this. Think about the `ArrayList.clear()` method. What it does is to empty the `ArrayList`, so that its size is then zero. You'd test this method by:

1. Creating an `ArrayList arr`;
2. Adding some things to it;
3. Invoking `arr.clear()`;
4. Checking `assertEquals(arr.size(),0)`.

In other words, you're setting things up so that your `ArrayList` has a state you don't want (`size()>0`); then you're invoking the method that should have a predictable effect on the state (setting `size()` to `0`); then checking that the effect is as you expected.

Comment: What if you wouldn't actually need the method size() in my implementation? Should I create it so that the testing class can use it?

Comment: Well, the point is that the method being tested must have some effect on the state, and that change in state must be detectable with the methods you've got already... or else either the method is pointless, or you need some more methods! In other words, if you don't have any methods that act differently depending on whether you've cleared the `ArrayList`, there would never be any point in clearing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test these method if you are using these method in other methods as a side effects.
As for example-

```
public class test{
public int i=0;
public void incrementIngeterValue()
{
  //doing something and 
   i++;
}

public boolean incremented()
{
  //some logic to check what is current i value
  int x = incrementIngeterValue();

  if(x==i)
       return false; // value not incremented
  else
       return true // in this case you can make sure this value is incremented by 1.


}
```

So you can test incremented method for checking i value is incremented by 1 or not, with this method you are internally test your incrementIngeterValue() without parameter and return value.

In  your case you a1 is effected in both methods. somewhere you are using this a1.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're trying to test the side-effects of the call, rather than the output (e.g. return value) of the call itself. You can test this in a number of different ways:

1. If the side-effects are visible, test that their results match your expectations
2. If the side-effects are not easily visible because they call into external interfaces, use a [mocking framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) such as [PowerMock](http://powermock.org/) to replace the external interface with mock objects so that you can observe and test against the calls to the external interface
3. Redesign your interface to be more testable. :)

In your specific case I'd add an accessor for al and check its contents match expected after the call to AMethod().

In general for unit testing, you don't want to connect to external URLs, databases, etc because it's slow and expensive. You want to replace those calls with data-providers which can simulate them instead.