# How to test java class using Junit. dont know where to start from

Tags: junit

Hello experts,
               I would like to start the Junit/mockito etc test framework as I have seen lots of blogs and even here itself people are suggesting to write test cases instead of sysout and all.. but I have been really struggling with testing :-(..
I went through tutorials and most of tutorial shows example of doing tests of sum sum, divide, addition etc.. ok I understood that but how I can use it in real life programming. Can some one please guide me and help writing the test case for example below VOID method:

```
public void callHtmls(List<String> pathList, Session session, Image img){
    Iterator<String> it = pathList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String path = it.next();
        String htmlPath = getHtmlPath(path); // call to a method
        if(htmlPath!=null){
            System.out.println("HTML Path is = " + htmlPath);
            try {
                callImagePrinter(htmlPath,session, img); //again call to a method
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me!!!!! I am having a nightmare because of the testing :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test void method with Junit testing tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244541/how-to-test-void-method-with-junit-testing-tools)

Answer (score 0):

First find the dependencies:

- input:

  - pathList, session, img
  - getHtmlPath()
- output

  - callImagePrinter()
  - System.out

Then define what you want to test.

1. The System-Output for a given pathList, session, img (probably easiest and best)
2. That getHtmlPath is used if pathList is non-empty
3. That callImagePrinter is called if pathList is non-empty
4. That System.out is written to in the failure case

Example:

For stubbing the input with Mockito:

```
YourObject spy = spy(yourObject);
when(spy.getHtmlPath()).thenReturn("htmlpath");
```

then call your method:

```
callHtmls(asList("html1","html2"), null, null);
```

and verifying the output of callImagePrinter:

```
verify(spy).callImagePrinter(eq("htmlpath"), any(Session.class), any(Image.class));
```

Note that `spy`,`when`,`eq` and `any` are static methods of `Mockito`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for explanation. I am using the sysout only to check if i have correct path but want to remove it once i use the test cases. I understand the explanation but dont know how to implement it as a Junit/Mockito..

Comment: I appended an example with Mockito.